# NPM Workspaces - Some modules installed to local node_modules dir

Tags: npm, npm-workspaces

I use npm workspaces. When I install a package for a workspace using `nmp i somepackage -w workspace-a` it is placed in to the same directory with the workspace if the installed version is different from root version.

I want to move it to a sub dir of root node_modules dir. Is it possible?

**current behaviour:**

```
root
|--node_modules
|  |--somepackage
|--workspace-a
|  |--node_modules
|  |  |--somepackage
|  |--package.json
|--package.json
```

**what I want is something like:**

```
root
|--node_modules
|  |--somepackage
|  |--workspace-a
|  |  |--node_modules
|  |  |  |--somepackage
|--workspace-a
|  |--package.json
|--package.json
```

Comment: Having a similar problem, something is causing `npm install` to created a `node_modules` folder at the workspace level, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: No. I just accepted it as it is :)

Comment: I managed to solve it by resolving dependencies version conflicts, as suggested by @dmudro answer.

Answer (score 11):

> if the installed version is different from root version

is the key here and it's probably not possible as I can see why npm behaves correctly and installs 'duplicate' version in `root/node_modules`.

in my case I had React 18 along other deps correctly defined in `workspace-a/package.json` (by installing via `npm install react -w worskspace-a`). yet React 18 was installed in local `worspace-a/node_modules` while and React 17 in `root/node_modules` which was causing issues in the app runtime. there should be only one instance: React 18 in `root/node_modules`.

this was caused by one other sub-sub dependencies in `workspace-a` depending on react <=17 so `npm install` would install v17 *additionally* in `root/node_modules`. hence my correct behaviour note earlier.

I was able to get rid of the issue by defining peer dependency React 18 on the root level but it's all at risk of using peer deps conflicts and overrides (as npm would warn you). in my case the ultimate fix will be redefining deps in the other library (and their package.json) I am using in workspace a.

Comment: You are right, this ended up being the problem in my case. I had some dependencies requiring React 18 instead of 17, that caused npm to create a `node_modules` folder inside one of the workspaces.

Comment: Have you tried `npm install --legacy-bundling`?